# .Net7 issue with AOT compilation: "Workload ID wasm-tools is not recognized" after dotnet workload install wasm-tools

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I'm decided to use the AOT compilation with a .Net7 Blazor WASM app and having no luck with publishing.
After entering> dotnet workload install wasm-tools
I get "Workload ID wasm-tools is not recognized." error message.
I can't seem to find what package is needed to get this to work (using VS2022 fully updated and have the .Net7 SDK installed - all .Net7 apps work just fine, so it's not that).
Either a package is missing, or, once again, VS2022 bug is rearing it's head (and has to be reinstalled for the nth time).
Any ideas?